# Problema al crear tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un error a la hora de crear tablas y no me doy cuenta.
Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda.

```
CREATE TABLE `marketcambd`.`Productos` (`ID` TINYINT (5) UNSIGNED NOT
NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(`ID`), UNIQUE(`ID`)) TYPE = InnoDB
/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci */ ;
```

Comment: que error te da? en principio eso es un problema de sql, no de php, javascript, css ni html... deberias etiquetarlo correctamente

Comment: ---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = InnoDB /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARSET utf8 COLLATE ut
---------------------------

Comment: Ese error me da, ya verifiqué que sea utf8 como la BD que creé, y aún así no funciona.

Comment: no se escribe type innoDB, se escribe engine = InnoDB

Comment: Pasa que eso me lo hizo automático, uso HeidiSQL4.0

Comment: Ya me anduvo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Si la declaras como `PRIMARY KEY` no tienes por qué declararla como `UNIQUE` también.

Comment: Si, ya me di cuenta de eso, gracias igual

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, me podrias decir como lo solucionaste?

Comment: Cuando creás la tabla, en la Query aparece con el TYPE, lo que tenés que hacer es sustituir los TYPE por los ENGINE.

Comment: y porque no pones eso como respuesta y la aceptas luego de 24 hs? es valido responder a tu pregunta comentando todas las cosas que hizo mal la ide y como las arreglaste...

Comment: bueno, pasa que nadie había respondido a mi pregunta en forma de "respuesta". lo pongo ahí como respuesta, a ver si te gusta más.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creás la tabla, en la Query aparece con el TYPE, lo que tenés que hacer es sustituir los TYPE por los ENGINE